# How to close the status bar/notification panel after notification button click

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I've browsed through Stackoverflow and have seen that this question has been asked, but I didn't find any solution.

I have a custom notification with 2 buttons. I want the status bar panel to close after I press a button on that notification, but don't know how. If I press the notification itself (so the contentIntent), then the panel closes, which is what I also want for my buttons.

Here's my notification code:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Service running", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.contentIntent = openIntent;
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);


contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, stopIntent);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, addIntent);

notification.contentView = contentView;

notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6435373/115145 Buttons are supported as of API Level 11. You indicated in your comment on my now-deleted answer that this is your `minSdkVersion`, and so you should be OK, though I have no idea how to close the drawer. My apologies for my error -- I had forgotten that they officially started supporting this.

Comment: Np, maybe I should have mentioned upfront that my minSdkVersion = 11 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution. It's not public API, but it works (for the moment):

```
Object sbservice = c.getSystemService( "statusbar" );
                    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
                    Method hidesb = statusbarManager.getMethod( "collapse" );
                    hidesb.invoke( sbservice );
```

For this to work

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

is needed

Comment: @iDroidExplorer: c is the Context. And, as asked in my question, this code is able to close the expanded notification bar panel. I use that piece of code after I press a button of my custom notification

Answer (score 121):

Use the following two code line to collapse the notification bar.

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```

Comment: This is the right answer because this code works without private API.

Comment: Correct and best answer.

Comment: Doesn't get easier than this, definitely the right way to do things

Answer (score 2):

### For Android 11 and below:

Provide permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>`

then:

```
Object statusBarService = context.getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method collapse = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
collapse.invoke( statusBarService );
```

### For Android 12 and above:

Either your app should be system app
Then with the same permission used above the method will work

For third-party apps..
This working is no available

```
/**
 * Collapse the notifications and settings panels.
 *
 * Starting in Android {@link Build.VERSION_CODES.S}, apps targeting SDK level {@link
 * Build.VERSION_CODES.S} or higher will need {@link android.Manifest.permission.STATUS_BAR}
 * permission to call this API.
 *
 * @hide
 */
@RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.STATUS_BAR)
@UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.R, publicAlternatives = "This operation"
        + " is not allowed anymore, please see {@link android.content"
        + ".Intent#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS} for more details.")
@TestApi
public void collapsePanels() {
  ...
}
```

and using **Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS**

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)