# Close status bar when button notification is clicked

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, statusbar

How can I close status bar after notification button click?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15571784/1735077), but I had an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: collapse []
   at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
   ...
```

My code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentTitle("Sync Failed")
    .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"))
    .addAction(R.drawable.change, "Change Pass", pChangePass)
    .addAction(R.drawable.remove, "Ignore", pIgnore)
    .setAutoCancel(false);
mNotificationManager.notify(accountUnique, builder.build());
```

At NotificationIntent class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int notificationID = intent.getExtras().getInt("NOT_ID");
    this.callbackContext = StatusBarNotification.getCallback();
    this.mNotificationManager = StatusBarNotification.getNotificationManager();

    this.mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationID);
    this.callbackContext.success(returnJSON(intent));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.

```
private int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
...

Object sbservice = context.getSystemService("statusbar");
try {
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    if (currentApiVersion <= 16) {
        Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
        collapse.invoke(sbservice);
    } else {
        Method collapse2 = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
        collapse2.invoke(sbservice);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should really accept Sam Lu's Comment - your solutions might stop working on any next versions, because it uses non public api. As you see you alredy had to add `if api<=16` - it's possible that soon you'll need to add `if api<=19`

Comment: Agreed with above comment. Sam`s answer is much simpler and does not deal with version numbers.

Comment: After api 31 ```statusBarManager!!.getMethod("collapsePanels")``` not working since they hide it.

Answer (score 36):

The following solution should be more simple and no non-public APIs used:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```

Comment: Can you tell where to use this, in onRecieve or action intent ?

Comment: Work like charm ! Thanks. Just put 2 code lines in onRecieve.

Comment: In latest android api 31+  its required ```android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS``` since its system app permission we cant use this way