# How disable close notification panel after click on own notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

How I can disable closing notification's panel after user click on my notification (on body, not action buttons)?

I use `notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)` and  `notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel( false)` but panel continues to be closed. What I doing wrong?

**Add:** I also use this code:

```
  Intent intentNotification intentNotification = new Intent( contextApplication, MyBroadcast.class);
  intentNotification.putExtra( "reload", "1");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( contextApplication, 0, intentNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  notificationBuilder.setContentIntent( pendingIntent);

  notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel( false); // this not work because setContentIntent work
```

If I remove this code notification panel stay showing on screen. When I add this code panel hide. But I need create call to MyBroadcast by click on notification body. Any way for call my broadcast by click on notification body?

**Add2:** On @NIPHIN answer I try restore natification panel inside my broadcastreceiver:

```
if( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 16)  Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager").getMethod( "expand").invoke( contextApplication.getSystemService( "statusbar"));
 else  Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager").getMethod( "expandNotificationsPanel").invoke( contextApplication.getSystemService( "statusbar"));
// manifest need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

This work correct, but not clear: panel first close and after few moments (seconds) restore.

Any way for disable closing panel?

Comment: Could you find a way to solve this without ever closing the bar?

Comment: No, I don't find solutions without closing the bar :(

Comment: I've found that you can use RemoteViews for that. tomahawk player is open source and is able to do that. Take a look at their PlaybackService.java file to see how they do it.

https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android.git

https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk-android/blob/master/src/org/tomahawk/tomahawk_android/services/PlaybackService.java

Answer (score 3):

use `notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false)`

To Close status bar use this

```
private int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Object sbservice = context.getSystemService("statusbar");

try {
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
    if (currentApiVersion <= 16) {
        Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
        collapse.invoke(sbservice);
    } else {
        Method collapse2 = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
        collapse2.invoke(sbservice);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

as per this answer  [Close status bar when button notification is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434014/close-status-bar-when-button-notification-is-clicked)

Comment: I need protect panel from closing. I add above info in question

Comment: addAction need button on bottom my notification, but if my notification not first in list buttons hidden (show by swype down on notification). And my click on notification will close panel.

Comment: I try use your code for retore panel. Work correct. But need any way for disable closing panel

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can do this. If you see the AOSP code of Notification click, Immediately after 
the click is handled in ClickHandler, the Panel is being closed

The below code is from BaseStatusBar.java

```
       try {
            mBarService.onNotificationClick(mPkg, mTag, mId);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }

        // close the shade if it was open
        animateCollapsePanels(CommandQueue.FLAG_EXCLUDE_NONE);
```

Comment: It is possible because Google Music App is able to do that!

http://i.stack.imgur.com/B5qh7.jpg

Comment: @PedroD in case of music app, its not the notification thats being clicked, its the remote views. Question was for the whole notification

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in builder :-

`setAutoCancel(false)`

Comment: Try this way http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL

Comment: I add above info in question

Answer (score -1):

```
    nm.cancel(uniqueID);
```

where nm is your object of NotoficationManager

Comment: I need disable closing notification but your enable and doing closing notification.