# Android remoteViews with buttons , when click the button, the notification bar can not pack up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, click

I have customized a `notification` with the `remoteviews`, the view contains layouts and two buttons, what I want is that when users click a layout which named "contentLayout", the activity "Test" will be opened, and when Users click  buttons, "remindTenMinButton" or "remindLaterButton", the action "Test2" will started.now the problem is the activity "Test" started correctly, but for the activity "Test2", when I clicked the button in the notification bar, it seems nothing happened, but when I click the "back", when the notification bar fold back, I can see the Test2 has already started, so the question is how to make the notification bar fold back when user click the button in the remoteview?
below are my codes:

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.example.androidtest2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            String notifyTitle = "title....";

            String notifyContent = "content......";

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(MainActivity.this
                    .getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_bar);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, notifyTitle);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.content, notifyContent);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder
                    .create(MainActivity.this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Test.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
                    .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            Intent notifyLaterIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NotificationProcesssingReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent PendingNotifyLaterIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, notifyLaterIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Intent notify10LaterIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NotificationProcesssingReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent PendingNotify10LaterIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                            notify10LaterIntent, 0);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentLayout,
                    resultPendingIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.remindLaterButton,
                    PendingNotifyLaterIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.remindTenMinButton,
                    PendingNotify10LaterIntent);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.audioStreamType = android.media.AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER;

            notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

            notification.tickerText = "ticker text...";

            notification.bigContentView = remoteViews;

            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        }
    });
}
}
```

**NotificationProcesssingReceiver**:

```
package com.example.androidtest2;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationProcesssingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent test = new Intent(context, Test2.class);
        test.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //context.startActivity(toMainScreen);
        context.startActivity(test);
    }
}
```

**Test**:

```
public class Test extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    /* NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     mNotificationManager.cancel(1);*/

}
```

}

**Test2**:

```
    public class Test2 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:text="Button" />
      </RelativeLayout>
```

**notification_bar.xml**:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/desk_command_oye" />

         <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title...."/>
     <TextView  android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    <Button    android:id="@+id/remindTenMinButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1"/>
     <Button    android:id="@+id/remindLaterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button2"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_test.xml**:

```
               <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >
       <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_test2.xml:

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidtest2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest2.Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.androidtest2.NotificationProcesssingReceiver" >
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtest2.Test2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test2" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the question, use below code:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```

For the detail, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568754/how-to-close-the-status-bar-notification-panel-after-notification-button-click):