# Allow activity to appear above expanded status bar / notifications panel on Android

Tags: android

I have an alarm app. After recent changes to Android Q, I need to use notifications to ring the alarm. When an alarm rings, the notification goes to status bar after some time. User can expand the status bar to look at the notifications. There are some notification actions that a user can use to interact with the alarm. One of the notification actions is snooze. When user taps on it, I show an activity that has the snooze durations. That activity appears behind the expanded status bar and hence not completely visible. (See screenshot below. You will see the "1 day" snooze duration. Rest are above it and hence hidden behind the notifications panel). How can I make this activity appear above the expanded notifications panel?

[image]

The snooze duration activity is defined as below in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".alarmmanager.SnoozeAlarmActivityDialogAlert"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/snooze_dialog_alert" />
```

Comment: Can you show us how you attach the notification? It's important what pending intents you use because some flags actually makes the notifications panel to close, such as `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. What you actually need to do is to close the notification panel instead of drawing over it, because for all I know it's impossible since Android Oreo (API 26).

Comment: Thanks @FurkanYurdakul. I have found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568754/how-to-close-the-status-bar-notification-panel-after-notification-button-click to close the system dialogs which also closes the notification panel.